# Carrierwave: Process Temp file and then upload via fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am processing a pdf uploaded by an user by extracting the text from it and saving the output  in an text file for processing later.

Locally I store the pdf in my public folder but when I work on Heroku I need to use S3.

I thought that the pdf path was the problem, so I included

> if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?

But still I receive

> ArgumentError (input must be an IO-like object or a filename):

Is there a way of temporarily storing the pdf in my root/tmp folder on Heroku, get the text from it, and then after that is done, upload the document to S3?

```
def convert_pdf
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.cucumber?
        pdf_dest = File.join(Rails.root, "public", @application.document_url)
    else
        pdf_dest = @application.document_url
    end
    txt_file_dest = Rails.root + 'tmp/pdf-parser/text'

    document_file_name = /\/uploads\/application\/document\/\d{1,}\/(?<file_name>.*).pdf/.match(@application.document_url)[:file_name]

    PDF::Reader.open(pdf_dest) do |reader|
        File.open(File.join(txt_file_dest, document_file_name + '.txt'), 'w+') do |f|
            reader.pages.each do |page|
                f.puts page.text
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to set up a custom processor in your uploader. And on top of that, since the output file (.txt) isn't going to have the same extension as the input file (.pdf), you're going to want to change the filename. The following belongs in your Uploader:

```
process :convert_to_text

def convert_to_text
  temp_dir = Rails.root.join('tmp', 'pdf-parser', 'text')
  temp_path = temp_dir.join(filename)

  FileUtils.mkdir_p(temp_dir)

  PDF::Reader.open(current_path) do |pdf|
    File.open(temp_path, 'w') do |f|
      pdf.pages.each do |page|
        f.puts page.text
      end
    end
  end

  File.unlink(current_path)
  FileUtils.cp(temp_path, current_path)
end

def filename
  super + '.txt' if original_filename.present?
end
```

I haven't run this code, so there are probably some bugs, but that should give you the idea at least.